# Another betweenness centrality measure: neighbourhood centrality

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, terminology, random-graphs

Among the many [centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality) measures that I have heard of, I miss the following (but maybe I'm just blind).

Consider a graph $G$ with $k$ connected components $G_i$ of size $|G_i|$. The number of node pairs in $G$ that are not connected by any path in $G$ is

$$D(G) = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{k} |G_i|\cdot|G\setminus G_i|$$

For connected graphs $D(G)$ is $0$, for empty graphs $D(G)$ is $\frac{1}{2}|G|(|G|-1)$. Let

$$d(G) = \frac{2}{|G|(|G|-1)} D(G)$$

be the proportion of node pairs that are not connected in $G$, so the empty graphs have $d(G)=1$.

Now consider $G$ as the [vertex-deleted subgraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstruction_conjecture#Formal_statements) of another graph $G\cup\{\nu\}$ with $\nu \not\in G$, where $\nu$ is connected to all nodes in $G$. In this case $G\cup\{\nu\}$ is obviously connected, and $\nu$ connects all pairs of nodes that have been disconnected in $G$. So it's natural to assign the number $d(G)$ to the node $\nu$ and call it for example its *connecting centrality* in  $G\cup\{\nu\}$ (just to give it a name).

Connecting centrality in this sense is only defined for nodes that are connected with all other nodes in a graph. But graphs with nodes that are connected to all other nodes are very rare, and [so are graphs that become disconnected by removing one single node](https://keplerlounge.com/math/2019/07/02/connected-graphs.html). so this concept might seem pointless. But **every** graph $G$ contains as many such graphs as there are nodes: the ego-networks $N(\nu) \cup\{\nu\} $, i.e. the induced subgraphs consisting of the node $\nu$ and all of its neighbours $N(\nu)$.

From a local perspective these ego-networks are interesting objects in themselves, even though they don't tell so much about the global properties of the surrounding graph. Ego-networks have two important properties: They contain a node that is connected to all other nodes, and the vertex-deleted subgraph $N(\nu)$ is disconnected more often than not, at least in sparse graphs. So it is quite natural to assign in *any* graph $G$ to *any* node $\nu$ its local connecting centrality $d(N(\nu))$ which now may be called *neighbourhood centrality*.

I have the following questions:

> 1. Under which name is this centrality measure already investigated?
> 2. How do neighbourhood and [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) (based on the number of *shortest* paths that go through a node $\nu$) correlate for
>    some typical graphs? (Think of a scatterplot.)
> 3. What might this correlation tell about the graph?

---

Comment: This seems to convey essentially the same information (but not saying it is the same thing) as a flavor of efficiency (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efficiency_(network_science)) with respect to a modified version of the discrete metric that takes the value $\infty$ when a target is unreachable from a source.

Comment: @SteveHuntsman: Thanks for the hint. The article also considers ego-deleted ego-networks $N(\nu)$, only under the name $G_i$.

Comment: I would contest the statement that the ego-nets tend to be disconnected in general. In a graph with high local clustering coefficient, I would expect then to be connected more frequently than not.

Comment: I think Leo has a point, and I would go further: ego-networks in a given network are very different from each other. Think of their size, which is nothing but vertex degrees: they are very heterogeneous in many (most?) practical cases; in addition, many degrees are extremely small. Although interesting, comparing the properties of graphs with such differences and such small sizes seems difficult.

Comment: @MatthieuLatapy: I didn't suggest to compare ego-networks (which may differ a lot) but large graphs (of a given class, e.g. $G(n,m)$). For each such graph the **distribution** of neighbourhood centrality can be determined (which will reveal the diversity and heterogeneity of nodes and their ego-nets) and will be roughly the same in  large classes (of large graphs).

Comment: I see, thank you for explaining further. Indeed, the distribution of neighbourhood properties, like their size (vertex degree), density (clustering coefficient), and others (like the neighbourhood centrality that you define) sheds light on important network features. Correlations between these metrics are also important.